# Solomonoff induction , Shannon Entropy, Kolmogorov Complexity.

Tags: entropy, artificial-intelligence, kolmogorov-complexity

If Expected Kolmogorov Complexity equals Shannon Entropy why can't Shannon Entropy be used as an approximation of Kolmogorov Complexity in Solomonoff Induction?

Regarding Kolmogorov Complexity and Shannon Entropy:  http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0410002.pdf